# Importing GWT project to IntelliJ fails

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, intellij-idea

I have a GWT project, which builds under Eclipse, but I am trying to migrate it to IntelliJ.

I appear to have imported it correctly, downloaded all the required libraries using maven / pom.xml, but when I try to make the project, I get the following error:

```
java: package com.infoshare.clearcore.shared.model does not exist
```

If I browse the sources, it is there, but using any of the IDE "goto" options fail.

The picture below shows the project structure, which has two modules one with the failing (auto generated) source code, and the other with the "`com.infoshare.clearcore.shared.model`" code. Is there some way I can tell the compile to look in both modules, or do I have to restructure the code?

[image: IntelliJProject]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you import the project? The best way I found to import Maven projects is simply to open the root pom.xml using `File > Open`, then IntelliJ will detect the project and import it automatically.

Eveything should be configured properly. in particular, the `target` folder should be displayed in another color, because the IDE knows it contains generated files (which is not the case in your current screenshot).

Comment: I used the `Import Project` option, but I did the import by specifying the root directory for the project, rather than the "`pom.xml`" file. Reimporting using "`pom.xml`" appears to fix the issue.